# ASP.NET MVC How to get FilePath pass into PeopleDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET using Entity Framework. I have different models for People, FileType and FilePath.  I want to display the image by retrieving the file path from FilPath together with data like name, age, etc. in index view.  I made it happen in Detail view, but in index view page I received error as "Value can not be null", which caused by the FilePath in PeopleDB is null.
Below is my code, please help.  Thanks.

/Model/PeopleDB.cs

```
namespace MvcDemo.Models {
    public class PeopleDB
    {
        public PeopleDB()
        {
         this.FilePaths = new HashSet<FilePath>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Interests { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
    }


    public class PeopleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PeopleDB> People { get; set; }      

    }

     }
```

/Model/FilePath.cs

```
 namespace Assessment_HC.Models
{        
    public class FilePath
    {
        public int FilePathId {get;set;}
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FileName {get;set;}
        public FileType FileType {get;set;}
        public int PersonID {get;set;}
        public virtual PeopleDB Person {get;set;}
    }    
}
```

Moedel/FileType.cs

```
    namespace Assessment_HC.Models
{
    public enum FileType
    {
        Avatar = 1, Photo
    }
}
```

Here is the controller for index view

```
//Get: /People/Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.People.ToList());
}
```

In db.People.ToList(), People.FilePath view is null.

In the controller, the detail view is like this, from where I can get the image showing on detail page:

```
// GET: /People/Details

public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    PeopleDB peopledb = db.People.Find(id);
    PeopleDB people = db.People.Include(i => i.FilePaths).SingleOrDefault(i => i.ID == id);
    if (peopledb == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(peopledb);
}
```

Thanks for your help.  Let me know if you need more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments, It seems the only thing you should do is changing `FilePaths` property of your `PeopleDB` to be `virtual` to work with Lazy Loading (which is enabled by default):

```
public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
```

Lazy Loading is enabled by default, and as stated in comments you didn't change it and there is nothing about Lazy Loading in your context constructor, So it seems the problem is in your `FilePaths` navigation property that is not virtual.

For index action:

```
return View(db.People.ToList());
```

For details action its better to do like:

```
var people = db.People.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
if (people == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(people );
```

But any way, If disable lazy Loading, you should use `Include` to include your navigation property in result. In this situation you can load data in your index action use:

```
db.People.Include(x => x.FilePaths).ToList()
```

or

```
//Remember to add using System.Data.Entity;
db.People.Include("FilePaths").ToList()
```

And to disable Lazy Loading you can

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Or in the constructor of your context:

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

**More information:**

> **[Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)**
>
> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of
>   entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that
>   a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using
>   POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of
>   derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the
>   loading hook.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  I just tried it, and got the same error, FilePath in PeopleDB is still null.

Comment: LazyLoading is enabled or disabled? The code of its constructor is not in your posted codes.

Comment: I don't know how to check the LazyLoading.  Here is what I have:public class PeopleController : Controller
    {
        private PeopleDBContext db = new PeopleDBContext();

Comment: @JialuZhu Look at your dbcontext class, in constructor, if there is  `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` then LazyLoading is disabled

Comment: Here is what's in what I have:     public class PeopleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PeopleDB> People { get; set; }      

    }

Comment: I don't think I disabled LazyLoading.

Comment: for enabling lazyloading :1) open edmx designer 2) press f4 3) change lazyloading state true or false in properties window؛ meantime on default  lazyloading is false.

Comment: Thanks Reza, I made it work by changing filepath to virtual.

Comment: @JialuZhu You are welcome, by the way, here in StackOverflow when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly accept it as answer and/or vote it up, to be more helpful for other users in future:)

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the code, the only one thing that you need is enabling [Eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager) using `Include` method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var model = _db.People.Include("FilePaths").ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

In this case all related file paths will be loaded.

You can also make FilePaths as virtual:

```
public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
```

And change your query this way:

```
var model = _db.People.ToList();
```

In both cases, all related file paths will be loaded.

Comment: By making the filepath virtual worked fine for me.  Thanks Sirwan.